# Differentiating between multiple objects attached to the same event handler

Tags: c#, events, button, methods, event-handling

I had a hard time figuring out how to search/phrase what I'm seeking to accomplish.  I'm looking to see if there is a safer/smarter way to achieve the following example.

Lets say I have 3 buttons with names:
btnOne
btnTwo
btnThree

The purpose of each button is to write a unique string to some textbox when clicked.  Since all three buttons do a very similar action, it seems logical to create one event handler for all three to use, but what would be a smart way for differentiating between the three buttons so that the proper textbox can get the correct string?  I don't like the current way I'm going about it:
pseudo, pseudo code:

```
private void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string buttonName = (sender as Button).Name;
    switch(buttonName)
    {
         case "btnOne":
             tbOne.Text = "This text is from button one";
             break;
         case "btnTwo":
             tbTwo.Text = "This is some different text";
             break;
         case "btnThree":
             tbThree.Text = "Button three text";
             break;
    }
}
```

The other way would be to have an on click event handler for each button which then has a common method like:

```
private void AfterButtonClicked(Textbox tb, string text)
{
    tb.Text = text;
}
```

Comment: Is this WinForms?  If so, all controls have a `tag` property of the `object` type so you can stick whatever you want in it.  It could be as easy as setting the `tag` property on each button and when it is clicked get the value from it and output it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the reused code is setting *some* textbox's `Text` property to *some* string. Personally I don't see the benefit of writing a single event handler in the way you've demonstrated *for the action that you've demonstrated*. IMHO it complicates the code rather than simplifies it.

You would be better off having three separate handlers that set the three separate textbox properties to the three separate strings. Then you would not have to do any further comparison to find out which button sent the event.

Depending on the *actual* application and the code inside the handler, this observation may or may not be valid.

---

However, one way you *could* refactor this would be:

```
Dictionary<Button, TextBox> buttonTextboxMap = new Dictionary<Button, TextBox> 
{
    {btnOne, tbOne}, 
    {btnTwo, tbTwo}, 
    {btnThree, tbThree}
};

Dictionary<Button, string> buttonStringMap = new Dictionary<Button, string> 
{
    {btnOne, "This text is from button one"},
    {btnTwo, "This is some different text"},
    {btnThree, "Button three text"}
};

void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;

    buttonTextboxMap[btn].Text = buttonStringMap[btn];
}
```

---

A second way would be to use each button's `Tag` property. I like this because it keeps everything encapsulated in the button itself. The downfall, though, is there is only one `Tag` property, and you are not guaranteed it holds the appropriate information. (You could also subclass `Button` to hold the proper information, but I suppose it depends on how much re-usability you are after and how many times you'll be using this particular button):

```
class TextBoxAndString
{
    public TextBox tb {get; set;}
    public String s {get; set;}
}

.ctor() //the form's constructor
{
    btnOne.Tag = new TextBoxAndString {tb = tbOne, s = "This text is from button one"};
    btnTwo.Tag = new TextBoxAndString {tb = tbTwo, s = "This is some different text"};
    btnThree.Tag = new TextBoxAndString {tb = tbThree, s = "Button three text"};   
} 

void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    TextBoxAndString tbs = (TextBoxAndString)btn.Tag;

    tbs.tb.Text = tbs.s;
}
```

Comment: Some kind of genius to use the tag property :)

Comment: Suppose there were 100 buttons, and they all needed to do something similar but required more uniqueness than a textbox and a string. By your solution I could create a class which contained each buttons unique parameters, a  list<*new class here*>, and then a common event handler which looked through the list for the class which corresponds to the button (preserving the refactoring).  This is also a great solution

Comment: @Justin Yeah I like the tag property (just saw your comment on the question :)). The only downside is it is not type-safe, but it's usually not a problem for storing simple "extra info"

Comment: @Doug Sure, although I'd recommend a dictionary rather than a list for fast access time. Or, throw it in the tag property as I've demonstrated, so you don't have to do the extra lookup. Again it depends on exactly what you're trying to do. As another example, you could store a key value in the `Tag` property which references a row in a `DataTable`.

Comment: I see your Tag idea now as well.  Probably better than my above comment.  I've used the tag property for treeview's before but didn't think for buttons for some reason.  I'll have to read up on Tags since I don't understand why its "not guaranteed [to hold] the appropriate information"

Comment: @Doug Simply because it's an object, and the existence of a value is not checked in the button's constructor. So you can't be guaranteed it holds any data at all, let alone data of type `TextBoxAndString`. That is, you could easily make a mistake somewhere and set `btnThree.Tag = 3.14159265` and the compiler will let you. Furthermore the property name "Tag" says nothing about the kind of information it holds, so looking at button.Tag is not necessarily intuitive. A well-placed comment explaining this usage should do it though.

Comment: @Doug The tag property is of the `object` type.  `Object` is the parent of **everything** in .NET so you could expect a `Dictionary<Control, string>` but it could be modified by anything else to change that to a `string` which means you cast would fail.  Kind of like how no one uses `ArrayList` anymore.  The `ArrayList` allowed you to insert anything into it so it could cause problems since you are expecting one thing and another type maybe there instead.

Comment: I understand, great explanations.  I'd select two answers because the "is" method will be beneficial to me as well, but the Tag looks like how I want to proceed.  Thank you both for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is such a simple case, I think I'd just leave them all in their own event handlers for sake of simplicity.

If you wanted to have one event though, you could test the `sender` by using:

```
private void Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is btnOne)
        tbOne.Text = "This text is from button one";
    else if (sender is btnTwo)
        tbTwo.Text = "This is some different text";
    else if (sender is btnThree)
         tbThree.Text = "Button three text";
}
```

At least then if you rename the buttons, your program will not compile, and you'll come in here to fix it.

The way you have it now, if you rename "btnOne" to "btn1", the text in `tbOne` will fail to update and you may not notice it.

Comment: Above was just an example.  It could be there are 100 buttons all doing something complex, similar enough to warrant one event handler, but still requiring unique methods depending on which button was clicked.  The "is" operator looks like a smarter way of going about it for sure